# Django OAuth Toolkit invalid_grant error

Tags: python, django, oauth

I have a bit of a problem, I have a django application that is using Django OAuth Toolkit and I can't  get the access token from the server when using Authorization Code flow. Implicit flow works fine. I haven't find anything regarding my problem on stack so I'm really sorry if this is a duplicate of another question.

I can authorize with this url and get the request come back, if i understand it correctly the request token is past in the code param.

http://mydomain.se/o/authorize?scope=read+write&state=kalle&redirect_uri=mycallbakurls&response_type=code&client_id=myclientid

when i then try to do a post to http://mydomain.se/o/token/ 
with:

```
grant_type = authorization_code
code = code from authorize call
client_id = my clientId
client_secret = my client secret
redirect_uri = my callback url
```

i get `"error" : "invalid_grant"` back.

Can someone please point me in the right direction what the problem can be?

Best regards Markus

Answer (score 19):

This can happen if the code is expired. They expire pretty quickly by default. You can look up your code in the Django admin under `Grants` and change the expiration date to far in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem when my client type is `confidential` rather than `public` in `o/application`. Here's how I solved it.

1. Failed error message is `{"error": "invalid_grant"}`

`curl -X POST -d "client_id=17U5rPQM1HDtF3hR8sIRP6pmzn033EbnwJJ6lNCx&    client_secret=D6bSgR8qyIwDl5SyF4kJ0wBJq56NXMUY9LVjD6NZTxnAh4ylTD2YBJxDBaLahpabZMGowWpVTYn6UW8Yq1GB6nAwm7euXZZxXaCxQLKK2KDNrfz4JSavFCKekc1LOCQz&grant_type=authorization_code&code=EaBVzVEjqbsU0GKl5gXK7ArrfsSiTJ&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Foauth_client%2F" http://localhost:8080/o/token/`
`{"error": "invalid_grant"}`

2. Then changed my client type to `public` and got `Success`.

`curl -X POST -d "client_id=17U5rPQM1HDtF3hR8sIRP6pmzn033EbnwJJ6lNCx&client_secret=D6bSgR8qyIwDl5SyF4kJ0wBJq56NXMUY9LVjD6NZTxnAh4ylTD2YBJxDBaLahpabZMGowWpVTYn6UW8Yq1GB6nAwm7euXZZxXaCxQLKK2KDNrfz4JSavFCKekc1LOCQz&grant_type=authorization_code&code=1ZxQjLN4QbpjaWgbztnOIe3K4bgxKj&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Foauth_client%2F" http://localhost:8080/o/token/`
`{"access_token": "KstIqSnt9Mj4ITmCGRJpTYW3W59nRv", "token_type": "Bearer", "expires_in": 36000, "refresh_token": "uJzJal9YSpirSax6vW2Di43ojRGvRV", "scope": "read write groups"}`

3. Again changed back to `Confidential` and send my username and password in curl request.

`curl -X POST -d "client_id=17U5rPQM1HDtF3hR8sIRP6pmzn033EbnwJJ6lNCx&client_secret=D6bSgR8qyIwDl5SyF4kJ0wBJq56NXMUY9LVjD6NZTxnAh4ylTD2YBJxDBaLahpabZMGowWpVTYn6UW8Yq1GB6nAwm7euXZZxXaCxQLKK2KDNrfz4JSavFCKekc1LOCQz&grant_type=authorization_code&code=UJnq1xfKULOUD0m2Oxb26NYmnuxKMn&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Foauth_client%2F" -u'admin:pass' http://localhost:8080/o/token/`
`{"access_token": "VhMgx59x4PHUPOgSTKMGewsM8JfT58", "token_type": "Bearer", "expires_in": 36000, "refresh_token": "T0BhP1lFvyiS9c5rH6xHqt4uBItAS1", "scope": "read write groups"}`

Answer (score 1):

I Found that I can't do the request separately. When I built my own client and tested all worked fine for me.

Comment: Hi! I'm facing exactly the same problem. Could you help me and explain a bit more of how you solved it? I've tried many things and I'm stuck to that problem ):

Answer (score 0):

Check to verify that you set your details correctly. For instance in my case my `client_id` was wrong.